# JQuery ajax post is empty on php remote server

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

When I run an ajax POST request on my localhost php server, $_POST array is filled. On a remote server the $_POST array is empty if I use google chrome, MS Edge; but $_POST is not empty on firefox.

When I investigated the HTTP Remote Address headers I noticed the following differences
 in chrome --- Remote Address: 95.168.185.183:8080
 in firefox ---Remote address:185.27.134.216:80

and if change the ajax call to type get, the code works well.

My ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php/designer/ajax_add_template_to_cart',
  type: 'post',
  datatype:'json',

  data:{
    template_name : template_name,
    size:size,
    qty: 1
  },

   error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
   },

  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

Comment: it does not seem likely that this issue originates with the above javascript code

Comment: seems like in all browsers which have a proxy connection : keep alive request header , $_POST is empty, these browsers are chromium based browser and MS Edge, but firefox and chrome for android dont have that header and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by doing code sequence change in AJax request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php/designer/ajax_add_template_to_cart',
  type: 'POST',
  data:{
    template_name : template_name,
    size:size,
    qty: 1
  },
  dataType:"JSON",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
   error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
   },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You must use valid URL
$.ajax({
url: 'index.php/designer/ajax_add_template_to_cart',
type: 'POST',
data: jQuery.param({ template_name: template_name, size: template_name ,qty:1}) ,
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
success: function (response) {
    alert(response.status);
},
error: function () {
    alert("error");
}
});
```

Comment: thanks... but the $_POST is empty, when i use developer tools to insept the request header data is being sent in all browsers...  but the server seeems to only receive data from firefox, and chrome android